# Magento 2 getTable behavior

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta, table

**TL;DR:** Is there any way in Magento 2 to make the method `getTable` from a resource collection model to return the same table name for 2 different parameters?

**Detailed Explanation**
I will start with an example from Magento 1.
Let's say I have a table called `module_entiti1_entity2`.
I needed to declare this table in my `config.xml` like this

```
<module_resource>
    <class>....</class>
    <entities>
         <entity1_entity2>
             <table>module_entiti1_entity2</table>
         </entity1_entity2>
    </entities>
</module_resource>
```

Then I can get the table name from a resource collection model for example like this:

```
$collection->getTable('module/entity1_entity2');
```

But if I want I can use multiple aliases for the same table.
If my `config.xml` section becomes

```
<module_resource>
    <class>....</class>
    <entities>
         <entity1_entity2>
             <table>module_entiti1_entity2</table>
         </entity1_entity2>
         <entity2_entity1>
             <table>module_entiti1_entity2</table>
         </entity2_entity1>
    </entities>
</module_resource>
```

I can retrieve my table in 2 ways:

```
$collection->getTable('module/entity1_entity2');
$collection->getTable('module/entity2_entity1');
```

In Magento 2 there is no more table declaration like above.
I can get my table name like this `$collection->getTable('module_entity1_entity2')`.
**Is there a way to tell magento that for the parameter `module_entity2_entity1` to return the same table name as for the parameter `module_entity1_entity2`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is `setMappedTableName`. Call this inside your resource model:

```
$this->_resources->setMappedTableName('module_entity1_entity1', 'module_entity1_entity2');
```

You can put this inside a function then call that before calling the `getTable` method.

Basically, it says that whenever I ask for `module_entity1_entity1`, give me the `module_entity1_entity2` table.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try it and come back with the results. By your recommendations, If I use the `setMappedTableName` in my resource model constructor it should work, right? That one gets called before any other method from the class.

Comment: True, I think that's the best place you can put it so it is mapped permanently. Unless you want it to work in specific cases only.

Comment: Hey. It works.  It would be nice if I can do this via `di.xml`. If it's not possible I will implement my own mechanism. But this is what I needed to get started. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm a fan BTW. It's my pleasure to be of help to you.