# Magento 2 How can declare table in config.xml

Tags: magento2

I want to declare table in config.xml 
I am put but that is not working

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <global>
        <models>
            <pwa_pay>
                <class>Pwa\Pay\Model</class>
                <resourceModel>Pwa\Pay\Model\ResourceModel</resourceModel>
            </pwa_pay>
            <pwa_pay_resource>
                <class>Pwa\Pay\Model\ResourceModel</class>
                <entities>
                    <demotable>
                        <table>demo_table</table>
                    </demotable>
                </entities>
            </pwa_pay_resource>
        </models>

    </global>
```

how can call in setup and modle in magento 2

And how can call in setup and model 
please see: [Magento 2 getTable behavior](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71203/magento-2-gettable-behavior)

Answer (score 1):

in magento2 we are not using any table in config.xml , in m2 config.xml is used for set default value , and also no where we are mention resources tag in xml just directly call the model and collection factory based on init it will generate the  collection

Comment: But in this case we change on model and setup.this is not good
and please see in this  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71203/magento-2-gettable-behavior